# How to get focus on sidebar in VSCode with keyboard

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I would like to get a focus as  on
picture 1

[image]

but when I am in folder like on this picture 2

[image]

I can get focus like on the picture 1 when I clicked ctrl + shift + e

For example: I write a code in index.js but then I want to get focus like on picture 1 and create folder with keyboard but I need get focus on this field.

Which is a shortcut I need to use for achive this goal?

Comment: Hm, interesting one. Closing and reopening the sidebar with `Ctrl + \ ` reenables the focus on `Ctrl + Shift + E` but it doesn't seem like the best approach.

Comment: I can  change focus if  I use mouse but  i'd like  to use keyboard

Comment: For example: I write a code  in  index.js but then I want to get focus like  on picture 1 and create folder with keyboard but I need get focus on this field

Comment: try key combo `Ctrl+0` (zero)

Comment: if I in folder index.js it will be switch on this folder but I need like on  picture 1

Comment: I found a decision I just need to click ```Esc``` button and all ok

Answer (score 1):

If you in the file for example like on picture 2 and you can get focus like on picture 1 you need press `Esc` button on your keyboard.